# Consolidate and sum values based on multiple conditions VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have 3 different data templates that are used for various activities. I need to consolidate the data that I receive in this 3 templates and was looking at a more universal approach but I can also copy same macro and tweak the parameters to fit all 3 templates so that shouldn't be much work I can have a user form and ask user what template they use and then I can fire one of the 3 macros. I am not very experienced in `Dictionary or Collection` so not too sure if for may case I used the right one. I went with a dictionary approach because I wanted to check for if key exists as I am looking for unique data after compilations. I used a dictionary in dictionary approach as I have one column that has a order number and in that I have multiple products that can be duplicates with different quantities. I require unique products for each order number and the duplicate products I need to sum their qty's. There is also other data in the sheet that I need to add back for each product so this will mean in my dictionary I had to join all columns after the sum the product qty. I have done in the past where I order the data and use reverse loop and add the qty while also mapping the duplicates to delete but I wanted to try and learn dictionary and collection see if there is any speed increase as the data tends to be over 100k rows and > 20 cols so I thought this would be a better approach. I am new to dictionary so any guidance will be much appreciated.

The problem with the below is that I cannot seem to find out where the data in the dictionary is going wrong so I don't seem to get the right output. The qty's off and also it's writing other data after the last row for some reason.

Sample Data:

```
Order NO | OtherData1 | OtherData2 | Product | Qty | OtherData3 | OtherData4 | OtherData5|>20col
10001    | 100        | GB         |111111111| 10  | 900-001    | UK1        | Descr     |
10001    | 100        | GB         |222222222| 100 | 900-001    | UK1        | Descr     |
10001    | 100        | GB         |111111111| 15  | 900-001    | UK1        | Descr     |
20001    | 100        | GB         |333333333| 25  | 900-001    | UK1        | Descr     |
20001    | 100        | GB         |111111111| 20  | 900-001    | UK1        | Descr     |
10001    | 100        | GB         |444444444| 30  | 900-001    | UK1        | Descr     |
10001    | 100        | GB         |555555555| 50  | 900-001    | UK1        | Descr     |
```

Desired output:

```
Order NO | OtherData1 | OtherData2 | Product | Qty | OtherData3 | OtherData4 | OtherData5|>20col
10001    | 100        | GB         |111111111| 25  | 900-001    | UK1        | Descr     |
10001    | 100        | GB         |222222222| 100 | 900-001    | UK1        | Descr     |
20001    | 100        | GB         |333333333| 25  | 900-001    | UK1        | Descr     |
20001    | 100        | GB         |111111111| 20  | 900-001    | UK1        | Descr     |
10001    | 100        | GB         |444444444| 30  | 900-001    | UK1        | Descr     |
10001    | 100        | GB         |555555555| 50  | 900-001    | UK1        | Descr     |
```

Here is my code:

```
Sub AddDuplicates()

    Dim dic As Object
    Dim dic2 As Object
    Dim Contents As Variant
    Dim ParentKeys As Variant
    Dim ChildKeys As Variant
    Dim r As Long, r2 As Long
    Dim LastR As Long

    ' Create "parent" Dictionary.  Each key in the parent Dictionary will be a disntict
    ' Code value, and each item will be a "child" dictionary.  For these "children"
    ' Dictionaries, each key will be a distinct Product value, and each item will be the
    ' sum of the Quantity column for that Code - Product combination

    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dic.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

    ' Dump contents of worksheet into array

    With ActiveSheet
        LastR = FindLastRow(ActiveSheet, 3, 21) '.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Contents = .Range("C17:U" & LastR).value
    End With

    ' Loop through the array

    For r = 1 To UBound(Contents, 1)

        ' If the current code matches a key in the parent Dictionary, then set dic2 equal
        ' to the "child" Dictionary for that key

        If dic.exists(Contents(r, 1)) Then
            Set dic2 = dic.Item(Contents(r, 1))

            ' If the current Product matches a key in the child Dictionary, then set the
            ' item for that key to the value of the item now plus the value of the current
            ' Quantity

            If dic2.exists(Contents(r, 3)) Then
                dic2.Item(Contents(r, 3)) = dic2.Item(Contents(r, 3)) + Contents(r, 4)


            ' If the current Product does not match a key in the child Dictionary, then set
            ' add the key, with item being the amount of the current Quantity

            Else
                dic2.Add Contents(r, 3), Contents(r, 4)

            End If

        ' If the current code does not match a key in the parent Dictionary, then instantiate
        ' dic2 as a new Dictionary, and add an item (Quantity) using the current Product as
        ' the Key.  Then, add that child Dictionary as an item in the parent Dictionary, using
        ' the current Code as the key

        Else
            Set dic2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            dic2.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
            dic2.Add Contents(r, 3), Contents(r, 4) 'Contents(r, 1),
            dic.Add Contents(r, 1), dic2
        End If
    Next

    Dim i As Long
    Dim tempVar As Variant
    For r = 1 To UBound(Contents, 1)
    If dic.exists(Contents(r, 1)) Then Set dic2 = dic.Item(Contents(r, 1))
    If dic2.exists(Contents(r, 3)) Then
        For i = 1 To 19
            If i <> 4 Then
                tempVar = tempVar & "|" & Contents(r, i)
                'dic2.Item(Contents(r, 3)) = dic2.Item(Contents(r, i))
            Else
                If tempVar <> Left(dic2.Item(Contents(r, 3)), Len(tempVar)) Then
                    tempVar = tempVar & "|" & dic2.Item(Contents(r, 3))
                    'dic2.Item(Contents(r, 3)) = dic2.Item(Contents(r, i))
                Else
                    'already in the right format now duplicates exit
                    tempVar = Empty
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
            'Debug.Print tempVar
        Next i
    End If
        If tempVar <> vbNullString Then
            dic2.Item(Contents(r, 3)) = tempVar
            'Debug.Print dic2.Item(Contents(r, 3))
            tempVar = Empty
        End If
    Next r


    Worksheets.Add    'for testing to delete after
    [a1:c1].value = Array("Code", "Product", "Qty")    'for testing to delete after

    ' Dump the keys of the parent Dictionary in an array

    ParentKeys = dic.keys
     For r = 0 To UBound(ParentKeys)
        ' Write the parent Dictionary's keys (i.e., the distinct Code values) to the worksheet
        LastR = FindLastRow(ActiveSheet, 1, 21)
        Set dic2 = dic.Item(ParentKeys(r))

        Range("B" & LastR).Resize(UBound(dic2.keys) + 1, 1).value = Application.Transpose(dic2.keys)
        Range("C" & LastR).Resize(UBound(dic2.keys) + 1, 1).value = Application.Transpose(dic2.items)
        Dim x As Long
        Dim dictCount As Long
        dictCount = dic2.Count
        Dim maxRecords As Long
        maxRecords = 999
        For x = 1 To WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(dic2.Count / 999, 0)
            LastR = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            If UBound(dic2.keys) > 999 Then
                If dictCount > 999 Then
                    dictCount = dictCount - 999
                Else
                    maxRecords = dictCount
                End If
                Range("A" & LastR).Resize(maxRecords, 1).value = Application.Transpose(ParentKeys(r) & "-" & x)

            Else
                Range("A" & LastR).Resize(UBound(dic2.keys) + 1, 1).value = Application.Transpose(ParentKeys(r))
            End If
        Next x

    Next r


    ' Destroy object variables

    Set dic2 = Nothing
    Set dic = Nothing

    MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong with your current results? You might want to consider an [mcve].

Comment: @SJR The qty after the macro runs is less then what I expected by doing a pivot table of the data. Also because I'm using 2 dictionary I think at some point something goes wrong because I find extra 20 rows of that that I wasn't expecting at the end. I am still debuting but no luck so far. I'm not really good with Dictionary so most likely I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I don't think we can diagnose the cause without knowing the precise details of how it goes wrong.

Comment: @SJR Basically I am getting a long string of data separated | at the end so my guess is somewhere at the joining of all columns or I am doing something wrong in the first dictionary and it writes that at the end. I will post a picture when I get a chance.

Comment: Your Product is shown in column 4 and Qty in column 5 but in the code you have dic2.Add Contents(r, 3), Contents(r, 4) ?

Comment: @CDP1802 I set watches on this and it comes out as the product and qty if I remember correctly but I will double check that to make sure thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code

```
Sub Test()
Dim a, ws As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet, txt As String, i As Long, ii As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
a = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value

With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For i = 2 To UBound(a, 1)
        txt = Join(Array(a(i, 1), a(i, 4)), Chr(2))
        If Not .Exists(txt) Then
            .Item(txt) = .Count + 1
            For ii = 1 To UBound(a, 2)
                a(.Count, ii) = a(i, ii)
            Next ii
        Else
            a(.Item(txt), 5) = a(.Item(txt), 5) + a(i, 5)
        End If
    Next i
    i = .Count
End With

With sh.Range("A1")
    .Resize(1, UBound(a, 2)).Value = ws.Range("A1").Resize(1, UBound(a, 2)).Value
    .Resize(1, UBound(a, 2)).Font.Bold = True
    .Offset(1).Resize(i, UBound(a, 2)) = a
    .Parent.Columns.AutoFit
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your help this works perfectly for what I needed. Are you able to provide more details to what is doing its simple but I don’t really understand what is happening there. Still trying to learn dictionary and how it works. If you can put some comments in your code what the lines are doing so I can learn. Also just wondering I am missing one piece from my original code and that is when I am writing the results back to the sheet I am looking at the ord no if > 999 rows for each ord then I need to split in more sets of 999 rows or remaining rows per that ord no. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. I am not so good at explanation. Try using F8 key to follow the code step by step and notice the local window and the variables. Generally in the variable a we stored the data then depending on two columns first and fourth we identify the unique key then populate the data and sum each unique key together and at last, putting the results in the second sheet and do some formatting.

Comment: thanks I am doing just that. Also working on a way to increment ord no if more than 999 rows. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a single dictionary and a composite key Order~Product. Use the dictionary to summate the quantities. Copy the full record to the output sheet on first occurrence of the key and after scanning all the data revisit the output to update the quantity.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SumDuplicates()

    Dim dictQu As Object

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, wsOut As Worksheet
    Dim iLastRow As Long, iOutRow As Long, iRow As Long
    Dim sOrder As String, sProduct As String, sKey As String
    Dim nQu As Single

    Set dictQu = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Sample Data
    Set wsOut = wb.Sheets("Sheet2") ' Output

    iLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    iOutRow = 2

    For iRow = 17 To iLastRow
        sOrder = ws.Cells(iRow, "C")
        sProduct = ws.Cells(iRow, "F")
        nQu = ws.Cells(iRow, "G")

        ' create composite key
        sKey = sOrder & "~" & sProduct

        If dictQu.exists(sKey) Then
            dictQu(sKey) = dictQu(sKey) + nQu
        Else
            dictQu(sKey) = nQu
            ' copy col C to W to output
            ws.Cells(iRow, 3).Resize(1, 21).Copy wsOut.Cells(iOutRow, 3)
            iOutRow = iOutRow + 1
        End If
    Next

    ' update total
    With wsOut
    For iRow = 2 To iOutRow - 1

        sOrder = .Cells(iRow, "C")
        sProduct = .Cells(iRow, "F")
        sKey = sOrder & "~" & sProduct

        .Cells(iRow, "G") = dictQu(sKey)
    Next
    End With

    MsgBox "OK"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks looks good I think I overcomplicated mine and I lost it. Yours is a lot cleaner. Question is it possible to copy the data column into an array after populating everything clear original data and populate it from array and update qty's? I added the data to new sheet so I can have the test data intact until I finalise the macro after I just want to do it in the same sheet. Also on that note do you think your code can be made to accommodate for 3 different templates where the data will be similar but in different columns that potentially are named differently by user? Thanks

Comment: @Quicksilver If you want to modify the existing sheet then scan up from the bottom and use dictionary to identify if duplicate and after the quantity has been added to the dictionary then delete the duplicate row. After that scan down the sheet to update the quantities. As for different templates I would first create 3 macros and then compare the extent of the differences to decide whether it makes sense to refactor into one.